# Replace getElementById wtih getElementsByClassName

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to replace `getElementById` with `getElementsByClassName`.

This is my original code.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
    function showDiv() {
        document.getElementById('loadingGif').style.display = "block"; //don't touch
        setTimeout(function () {
            document.getElementById('loadingGif').style.display = "none";//don't touch
        }, time);
    }
</script>

<div id="loadingGif" style="display:none">
    <img src="https://mir-s3-cdn-cf.behance.net/project_modules/disp/35771931234507.564a1d2403b3a.gif">
</div>
```

It works however when I change CSS `id` into `class` and `getElementById` into `getElementsByClassName` it no longer works.

What am I doing wrong, please?

Thank you

Comment: `getElementsByClassName()` always returns a **list** of elements.

Comment: You won't get an array, you will get an [`HTMLCollection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) which is a *live* reference to the DOM. To return a single element by class try `querySelector('.classname')`

Comment: @Pauline there's no reason to use `.map()` if a new array isn't needed; that's a job for `.forEach()`

Answer (score 1):

The getElementsByClassName is a method of DOM and returns an array-like object.

In order to access to one element you have to use one for or foreach.

```
const array = document.getElementsByClassName('loadingGif');
Object.keys(array).forEach((key) => {
    array[key].style.display = "block";
});

setTimeout(function () {
    Object.keys(array).forEach((key) => {
        array[key].style.display = "none";
    });            
}, time);
});
```

Try to use querySelector(".classname") instead getElementsByClassName.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @pilchard.

I have to replace `document.getElementById('loadingGif')` with `document.querySelector('.loadingGif')`.